# Filter jobs by full time, part time, remote?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it possible to filter jobs based on criteria like in the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can !!!

see the image for more details

- to select permanent/contract (select the drop down radio buttons, populated at search text box.
- to select 'to work remotely' , click on settings button beside matches.

[image: screenshot reference]

You can also play with URL to achieve this. Just replace the search term with your desired job title(replace 'space' by '+')

> java developer → searchTerm=java+developer

### Sample Urls for reference:

**permanent job**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+developer&type=permanent
```

**permanent job & allows remote**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+developer&type=permanent&allowsremote=True
```

**contract job**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+developer&type=contract
```

**contract job & allows remote**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+developer&type=contract&allowsremote=True
```

For more details, please read https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help

Comment: These are all just options you can click in the UI.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, added UI option details as well

Comment: I'll just state the obvious: Non of this applies to part-time vs full-time, since such a distinction does not exist on SO Jobs.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the UI we also have [advanced search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help) that allows searching by specific fields. For example:

[`type:permanent remote:true`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=remote%3Atrue+type%3Apermanent) searches for permanent remote jobs

[`title:"java developer"`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=title%3A%22java+developer%22) searches explicitly for jobs with "java developer" in the title

[`[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%5Bjava%5D) searches for jobs with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.

There's a bunch of other things you can do, see the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help) for more examples!